# Alternative to Vlookup that does not stop at first value found

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: Figure 1]

I am trying to populate B2:D5 with "yes"/"No" ( Figure 1) based on the criteria that if I find the respective pvalue( Column A) , in the 'Test' column in a separate sheet and the Fvalue matches the column header of figure 1. I tried using the formula visible in figure 3. However, it incorrectly labels the cow and chicken columns. Which I suspect is due to it stopping at the first " True" value it finds, and not iterating over the other values once it finds said true value.

[image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: what is the formula you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS()

In B2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,$A2,Shee1!B:B,B$1),"Yes","No")
```

Then copy over and down the grid.

Where Sheet1 is the list.

Comment: Awesome, can you explain what you're doing in the countif formula? Just for future reference

Comment: It counts the number of items that match both criteria in the list.  If it is greater than or equal to 1 then the IF reads it as true and returns "Yes", if it returns 0, no matches found, the IF sees that as FALSE and returns "No"